# Python : Can't install Pillow library on Pypy3.7 (7.3.1)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pypy

Pillow doesn't seem to install on Pypy3.7. I am running this on Mac OS, Catalina 10.15.4.

```
Pip3 install Pillow
```

returns:

```
 
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/sg/g7xccd2d5ql7cv01qg_3j0440000gn/T/pip-install-6bmk1_j2/pillow/setup.py", line 918, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

Is there anything I am missing here? All I see is the missing 'Zlib'. I tried to

```
brew install Zlib
```

And reinstalled Xcode just in case. Nothing seems to work. The odd thing is that it works fine with python3 pip, but not with pypy3 pip.

Comment: CPython uses a binary wheel, unfortunately Pillow does not supply a binary wheel just yet so you must compile from source. See https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4655#issuecomment-653846923, maybe in a few days the upload issue will be sorted out

Answer (score 0):

Try to change CPATH:

```
export CPATH=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include
```